# Excel VBA setting cells as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have read articles that have led me to change the first line into a variable but I need the "n94" to be a variable as well. It will always be 7 lines up and on the N column. I have to re-edit this in the future to 6 lines up etc... Trying to concatenate memo notes and its taking way too long with the amount of data.

```
Range("B101").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("N94").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Rows("95:101").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Its not clear what you have, and what you want to do

Comment: I am trying to copy cell B101 and special paste as values to cell N94 then delete the rows 95-101. After that I want to select another cell in Column B and repeat the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It will always be 7 lines up and on the N column

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Replace this with the actual sheet name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set rng = ActiveCell '<~~ From Comments below

        If (rng.Row - 7) < 1 Then
            MsgBox "Cannot Paste. Row Out of bounds"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        rng.Copy

        .Cells(rng.Row - 7, "N").PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

        '~~> Delete the rows. For example Rows("95:101")
        .Rows((rng.Row - 6) & ":" & rng.Row).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That is something like it. But I would like to click on the cell and let the macro run. If I have to change the section like B101 it would take longer than me manually doing it. If that could be a variable I would be most happy :) I have about 6000 rows left and I have been doing it manually.

Comment: Change `.Range("B101")` to `ActiveCell` :)

Comment: Almost there: I have Set ws = "ASM-Concatented Address w notes" and when I run it I get an input box to create a table and select my data cell. ~ Unsure what it means.

Comment: change `Set ws = "ASM-Concatented Address w notes"` to `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ASM-Concatented Address w notes")` I am assuming that you have a sheet with that name in your workbook.

Comment: Siddharth it is working awesome. Anyway that removing the 7 rows after the pasted cell. Like if the paste goes to n94 the rows 95 through 102 can be deleted.

Comment: 101 or 102? As per your question, it is supposed to delete till 101 only

Comment: 101 is correct. I run it the script and it copies the formula to the cell and it is a text value like I am looking for the but the rows are still there.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly from above. `.Rows((rng.Row - 6) & ":" & rng.Row).Delete Shift:=xlUp` line does the deleting part.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that but thank you so much. :) You make my week.